# Use of "the" before a defined entity?

Tags: articles, mathematics

Should we write:

"x is an element of vector X"
or
"x is an element of **the** vector X"?

I have always been taught to use the former formulation, but now am asked to use the latter. Am confused. Any help please?

Another example. When I introduce a point of a plane Delta already described, should I write

"Consider point P lying on plane delta" or
"Consider the point P lying on the plane delta"?

Comment: Context, context, context. Has X been mentioned before? And is *vector* part of the sentence, or part of your placeholder "vector X"?

Comment: I don't know, I am asking you. If that is meant as an answer to my question, please edit your post to include it.

Comment: X is not necessarily mentioned before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are at the mercy of house (or classroom) style, methinks. When I used to edit math books, the standard style at most publishers I worked for was to omit the definite article before mathematical entities:

> vector X, line AB, altitude *h*

I can't tell (because of your use of passive voice) who or what is asking you to include the definite article; but if the source is official (or institutional), I recommend that you abide by the directive. Even so, your previous understanding enjoys broader acceptance than the style that's new to you.

Answer (score 0):

If X has been mentioned before, then it will be clear to the reader you're talking about a vector and I'd write "x is a component of X" (I'm not sure why you wrote element; vectors have components, and the vectors themselves are the elements of the vector space).

If it hasn't, then I'd write "Let x be the i^{th} component of X", or something to that effect. I'd imagine the typesetting will tell them its a vector for you (the arrow on top, or the underline, or however you prefer).

Comment: But the bare term *X* may be a numeric or alphabetic index which acts as a component in the name of multiple entities.

Answer (score 0):

I think of it this way: "X" is the name you've given that vector, so the word "vector" ends up in that sentence functioning grammatically more like a title, similar to the way that you would say "Queen Elizabeth" rather than "the Queen Elizabeth." Why then isn't the word "vector" in "vector X" capitalized like how you would for other titles?  I take that to be because "vector" isn't really a title in the same sense of "Queen" or military titles, etc.

Comment: Indeed some suggested to write in Capital the fist letter of vector, but I find it weird and not so beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

As Sven Yargs says, house rules rule, whether the ‘house’ is a publisher or a style manual or an academic department or a discipline.

But in circumstances where you’re free to make your own rules, I suggest that you regard phrases like ‘vector X’ or ‘formula 1.3’, which completely and unambiguously identify specific entities, as *names* requiring no determiner.

It’s analogous to the distinction between ***the*** Prince of Wales, where *of Wales* defines which prince is being spoken of, and *∅ Prince Charles*, where *Prince* is a component of His Highness’ style.

Comment: but there should be a rule, no?

Comment: @polar There is not only a rule, there are several - at least one per House. This contributes substantially to economic prosperity in many academic disciplines by increasing opportunities for employment at publishing houses.

Comment: So it is not a question of difference between British and American styles? Please, could you explain with more detail the fact that difference in style can lead to job creation?

Comment: Re: "increasing opportunities for employment at publishing houses." Would that it were so.

Comment: @polar Not that I'm aware of. But I don't read enough math in either dialect to assert that with any confidence.

Comment: @SvenYargs Would you buy "slowing the decline in opportunities &c"?

Comment: The only thing that working with multiple unique house styles (versus a generalized style of the pre-15th Edition CMOS type) ever did for me was to lower my effective hourly pay rate, by requiring repeated time-wasting forays into the house style guide. Most manuscripts have quite enough trouble saying things clearly to keep copy editors in business forever (barring the death of print publishing). On the in-house side, meanwhile, style guides tend to be monstrosities under no one's comprehensive superintendence, with new rules accreting haphazardly like polyps—so no job opportunities there.

Comment: @SvenYargs It's reassuring to hear that copyeditors are still employed at all. In my line of writing editing is handed off to semi-literate attorneys in the Compliance Departments, whose primary function appears to be that of obfuscating anything which is clearly expressed.

Comment: I spent three years training to become a lawyer before (in effect) taking a vow of poverty and becoming an editor instead, and I can tell you that your impression about those compliance department attorneys is correct: They do it on purpose.